# Products object disable list price and quantity

Tags: community, opportunity, product

is there any way to disable the list price and just use the standard price and also disable the quantity of the product in products object in salesforce? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the field security for those two fields, nor can you remove them from layouts, or make them read-only. However, you could always write a process, flow, workflow, or trigger to automatically force the values to be whatever you want. You'll probably get some questions from users about why their changes don't appear to be saving, so you'll want to be prepared for that eventuality.